# ¿Como sumar los items con "id" repetidos en un array de objetos?

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un **array** de **objetos**:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 438
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 25.0
    "producto" => "trio 2"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 357
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 70.0
    "producto" => "Seleccion marina mediana"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 402
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena de trigo"
  ]
  5 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  6 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 2
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  7 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
]
```

Intento de la sig manera:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $total = 0;
    $detalles = $array;
    foreach($detalles as $keyDet => $valueDet){
        if($value['fk_id_producto'] == $valueDet['fk_id_producto']){
            $total = $total+(intval($value['cantidad']));
        }
    }
    $array[$key]['cantidad'] = $total;
}
```

Me arroja el sig **array** de **objetos**:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 5
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 438
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 25.0
    "producto" => "trio 2"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 357
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 70.0
    "producto" => "Seleccion marina mediana"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 5
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 402
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena de trigo"
  ]
  5 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 5
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  6 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 10
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  7 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 5
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
]
```

Primer problema, no suma las cantidades sino las veces que se repite el item.
Segundo problema, no logro eliminar los repetidos sin que me cause error.

**Actualización 1:**
El **array** resultando que deseo obtener es algo parecido al sig ejemplo:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 401
    "cantidad" => 6
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena negra"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 438
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 25.0
    "producto" => "trio 2"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 357
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 70.0
    "producto" => "Seleccion marina mediana"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "fk_id_producto" => 402
    "cantidad" => 1
    "precio" => 9.0
    "producto" => "Cuzquena de trigo"
  ]
]
```

Donde se agrupen por **fk_id_producto** y se sumen las cantidades totales entre todos esos **fk_id_producto**.

Comment: Pablo, no es muy clara la pregunta. Cuando hablas de `sumar` debes decir claramente si lo que quieres es saber cuántos elementos hay repetidos o si es sumar los valores de esos elementos. Debes decir además sobre qué elementos se debe actuar, ¿sobre todos, sobre un elemento en específico? Luego dices algo de eliminar repetidos que tampoco se entiende muy bien. Si quieres que se elimine algo debes explicar cómo debería quedar el objeto luego de esa eliminación. Si es posible aclara un poco mejor lo que quieres hacer. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano actualice la pregunta con un ejemplo de lo que quiero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasos:

1. Identificar los productos únicos del conjunto, p.e. generando un array
   con las ids sin repeticiones
2. Usar cada id para generar un array con los productos repetidos que le
   correspondan, para poder sumar en uno la cantidad total.
3. Guardar cada producto único, actualizada "cantidad" en un nuevo array.

Datos:

$arr = [
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 401,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 9.0,
            "producto"       => "Cuzquena negra",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 438,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 25.0,
            "producto"       => "trio 2",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 357,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 70.0,
            "producto"       => "Seleccion marina mediana",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 401,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 9.0,
            "producto"       => "Cuzquena negra",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 402,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 9.0,
            "producto"       => "Cuzquena de trigo",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 401,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 9.0,
            "producto"       => "Cuzquena negra",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 401,
            "cantidad"       => 2,
            "precio"         => 9.0,
            "producto"       => "Cuzquena negra",
        ],
        [
            "fk_id_producto" => 401,
            "cantidad"       => 1,
            "precio"         => 9.0,
            "producto"       => "Cuzquena negra",
        ],
    ];

Codigo:

```
function dx($x): void
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($x);
    echo '</pre>';
}



// Create an array with the Ids withouts repetitions to get
// a list of unique products
$ids_products = [];
foreach ($arr as $arr_product) {
    $id_product = $arr_product["fk_id_producto"];
    if (! in_array($id_product, $ids_products)) {
        $ids_products[] = $id_product;
    }
}
// dx($ids_products); // trace

// Create array with the list of unique productos
$result = [];
foreach ($ids_products as $unique_id) {
    $temp     = [];
    $quantity = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $arr_product) {
        $id = $arr_product["fk_id_producto"];

        if ($id === $unique_id) {
            $temp[] = $arr_product;
        }
    }

    $product = $temp[0];


    $product["cantidad"] = 0;
    foreach ($temp as $product_temp) {
        $product["cantidad"] = $product["cantidad"] + $product_temp["cantidad"];
    }
    // dx($product["cantidad"]); // trace

    // store unique producto with updated quantity
    $result[] = $product;
}

dx($result); // trace
```

Resultado:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'fk_id_producto' => 401,
    'cantidad' => 6,
    'precio' => 9.0,
    'producto' => 'Cuzquena negra',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'fk_id_producto' => 438,
    'cantidad' => 1,
    'precio' => 25.0,
    'producto' => 'trio 2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'fk_id_producto' => 357,
    'cantidad' => 1,
    'precio' => 70.0,
    'producto' => 'Seleccion marina mediana',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'fk_id_producto' => 402,
    'cantidad' => 1,
    'precio' => 9.0,
    'producto' => 'Cuzquena de trigo',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas crear un array nuevo y agregar cada id una sola vez.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array("fk_id_producto" => 401, "cantidad" => 1), 
    array("fk_id_producto" => 438, "cantidad" => 1), 
    array("fk_id_producto" => 401, "cantidad" => 2)
);
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(array_key_exists($value['fk_id_producto'], $newArray)) {
    $newArray[$value['fk_id_producto']] += $value['cantidad'];
  } else {
    $newArray[$value['fk_id_producto']] = $value['cantidad'];
  }
}
var_dump($newArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando el código que tienes tu:

```
$detalles = $array;
foreach($array as $key => &$value){
    $total = $a[$key]['cantidad'];
    foreach($detalles as $keyDet => &$valueDet){
        if($value['fk_id_producto'] == $valueDet['fk_id_producto'] && $key != $keyDet){
            $total += intval($valueDet['cantidad']);
            unset($detalles[$keyDet]);
            unset($array[$keyDet]);
        }
    }
    $array[$key]['cantidad'] = $total;
}
```

1. Antes del primer `foreach` inicio el arreglo que usare interno.
2. Para que los cambios que se realicen dentro de los `foreach` sobre los Arreglos se modifiquen se deben pasar los `$value` con `&`.
3. La variable para sumar `$total` se inicializa en el valor del arreglo externo.
4. A la condición del `if` verifico que no coincidan las `key` de los Arreglos.
5. Para sumar en el total uso el valor del arreglo interno.
6. Se van eliminando de ambos arreglos en la posición donde se encontró que coinciden del arreglo interno `$detalles` que es el que se va recorriendo internamente.
7. Finalmente en <kbd>$array</kbd> te queda el arreglo que necesitas.

**unset**(http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php)

> Para poder modificar directamente los elementos del array dentro de bucle, se ha de anteponer & a $valor. En este caso el valor será asignado por referencia.
>   http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php